# User experience of auto moderators in platforms better at case resolution?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

It is known that well trained and programmed tools can be used to automate and perform tasks at a greater level of precision and accuracy than humans (most of the time). The fact that they can be perceived as impersonal and imperfect probably has more to do with the people that programmed them and the data used to train them.

However, reddit has implemented the [AutoModerator](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/automoderator/), which allows moderators to:

> define "rules" (consisting of checks and actions) to be automatically
> applied to posts in their subreddit. It supports a wide range of
> functions with a flexible rule-definition syntax, and can be set up to
> handle many common moderation tasks automatically.

I think that low interaction levels of rule based automation is generally deemed acceptable and useful for users (like input validation), while highly sophisticated levels of rule based automation (like sales funnels and the loops you have to take to opt out of services) are deemed morally and legally questionable.

What are some examples and experiences of the medium levels of rule based automation that have been applied successfully in social media platforms or website with high volume traffic (e.g. government websites) to create positive user experiences? Would the AutoModerator be considered such an example?